# fatal: 'stash'. Maybe git-stash is broken?

Tags: git

Есть изменения в индексируемом файле. Решил спрятать изменения набрав

```
git stash
```

Результат:

```
fatal: 'stash' appears to be a git command, but we were not 
able to execute it. Maybe git-stash is broken?
```

Как исправить?

Comment: Что если просто накатить гит заново? Может git-stash действительно сломан любым образом.

Comment: вот этот скрипт: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-stash.sh . в вашей инсталляции программа *git* не может его запустить по какой-то причине (отсутствие, повреждение файла, неправильные атрибуты, и т.д. и т.п.)

Comment: @Monk - накатил гит заново - не помогло